# RAII style API wrapper for PyMongo

Tags: python, wrapper, pymongo, raii

I just watched [Raymond Hettinger's talk](https://us.pycon.org/2015/schedule/presentation/416/) on making Python more Pythonic and realized I should be putting a lot of his ideas into practice, particularly wrapping API's in a class that makes everything simpler and easy to use. Here's what I'm doing to wrap PyMongo:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

class MongoDB(object):
    """Provides a RAII wrapper for PyMongo db connections.
    Available collection functions limited to those in
    attributes_to_pass. Number of simultaneous connection 
    users also tracked. """

    attributes_to_pass = ["update", "insert", "count"]
    client = None
    num_users = 0

    def __init__(self, db, collection):
        MongoDB.client = MongoDB.client or MongoClient()
        self.collection = MongoDB.client[db][collection]
        MongoDB.num_users += 1

    def __enter__(self, *args):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        MongoDB.num_users -= 1
        if MongoDB.num_users is 0:
            self.client.close()

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr in MongoDB.attributes_to_pass:
            return getattr(self.collection, attr)
        else:
            return getattr(self, attr)

def main():
    with MongoDB(db = "db1", collection = "c1") as m:
        print(m.count())
        m.update({"jello":5} , {"hello":"you"}, upsert = True)
        print(m.count())
        m.insert({"joe":6})
        with MongoDB(db ='db1', collection = 'c2') as j:
            j.insert({"joe":6})
            print(j.count())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I would really appreciate all suggestions on how to make this better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great that you provided a docstring! You made one minor formatting mistake though, there should be a blank line between your brief single line summary and the rest of the docstring. It's recommended in the style guide partially for readability and partially for script parsers.

```
class MongoDB(object):
    """Provides a RAII wrapper for PyMongo db connections.

    Available collection functions limited to those in
    attributes_to_pass. Number of simultaneous connection 
    users also tracked. """
```

It seems like `attributes_to_pass` is actually a constant. If that is the case it should be UPPER_SNAKE_CASE to be clear that it is, especially when mixed with attributes that often change like `client` and `num_users`. It should also be a tuple, as tuples are immutable so will not change unless updated in the source code.

```
ATTRIBUTES_TO_PASS = ("update", "insert", "count")
```

Also, when you call on these constants you refer to the class name. While that's possible I'd personally say it's less readable. I had thought you were calling on a class you imported for a second. You can just pass `self` instead of the classname.

```
def __getattr__(self, attr):
    if attr in self.ATTRIBUTES_TO_PASS:
        return getattr(self.collection, attr)
    else:
        return getattr(self, attr)
```